# How to write the following Matlab code in Eigen: vec(1:n) = vec(idx)?

Tags: c++, matlab, permutation, eigen

I'd like to transform the following Matlab code to Eigen code efficiently (i.e., without using a for-loop in order to take advantage of vectorization):

```matlab
idx = [2 4 1 3]; % index array
vec = rand(4, 1);  % vector to permute

vec(1:4) = vec(idx); % the operation I'd like to do in Eigen
```

Now I could simply do something like this in Eigen:

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
   vec.coeffRef(i) = vec.coeff(idx.coeff(i)); // without range-checking
```

but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: "in order to take advantage of vectorization" Vectorization is something that relates to MATLAB and other interpreted languages. If Eigen has a built-in method for this, it's going to have that same loop under the hood. In short, don't worry about what you think might be bottlenecks, implement your algorithm first, if it's too slow profile it to see what bits take most time and need your attention for improvements. It is unlikely that this bit here be a bottleneck in your algorithm.

Comment: With the development branch of Eigen you can write just `vec(idx)` (there are probably alignment issues if you assign it to itself -- I'd need to check that). But this does not get vectorized. Theoretically, this would be possible with AVX gather instructions, but they are probably not worth it, if you just want to store the result afterwards. With your example you might just want to look into [Permutations in Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PermutationBase.html).